# Transfer Data from AWS Time Stream to DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams, amazon-timestream

i am working in the IoT Space with 2 Databases. AWS Time Stream & AWS DynamoDB.
My sensor data is coming into Time Stream via AWS IoT Core and MQTT. I set up a rule, that gives permission to transfer the incoming data directly into Time Stream.

What i need to do now is to run some operations on the data and save the result of these operations into DynamoDB.

I know with DynamoDB there is function called DynamoDB Streams. Is there a solution like Streams in Time Stream as well? Or does anybody has an idea, how i can automatically transfer the results of the operations from Time Stream to DynamoDB?

Comment: Why not considering saving the result into Timestream?

Comment: At the end, users with the software Quantrix need to work with the data. But the Quantrix users only have access to the DynamoDB with help of a JDBC Driver.

Answer (score 1):

Timestream does not have Change Data Capture capabilities.

Best thing to do is to write the data into DynamoDB from wherever you are doing your operations on Timestream. For example, if you are using AWS Glue to analyze your Timestream data, you can sink the results directly from Glue using the [DynamoDB sink](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect.html#etl-connect-dynamodb-as-sink).

Answer (score 1):

Timestream has the concept of [Schedule Query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/scheduledqueries.html). When a query has ran, you can be notified via a [SNS topic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/scheduledqueries-notification.html). You could connect a lambda on that SNS topic to retrieve the query result and store it in DynamoDB.